# Dynamically size list of lists

Tags: python

I need a number of list, bot the number of lists and the length of the lists I don't know a priory. The type of the lists is str. How can I do this in an efficient way?

I tried:

```
data = [[]] * number_of_needed_lists
for line in f.readlines():
    columns = line.split(',')
        for i, dta in enumerate(data):
            data[i] =  dta + [columns[i]]
```

but this is very slow. I tried a similar structure but with a dictionary of lists, similar result.

Besides, I found the following strange behavior:

```
a = [[]] * 5
a[0] += [1]
a
==> [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
expected: [[1],[],[],[],[]]
```

Comment: Why are you not using `csv`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I forgot, I changed to this some time ago because CSV didn't do what I needed. I can try again, will it solve this problem? Still, curious how to make it work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
data = [[]] * number_of_needed_lists
```

with:

```
data = [[] for i in range(number_of_needed_lists)]
```

when you're using the `*` operator you're actually using a copy (of a reference) to the same object - and that is the reason why, when you change one of them - all of them change.

Comment: Genius! It's 30 times faster now, making it acceptable. I wish I had a thorough understanding of this reference business. I understand what a reference is, but to sniff out what happens when behind the scenes,...

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to know the length of the lists, you can simply use `list.append()` if you want to add something to a list.
Second, you can use a list that contains a set of lists, so for creating a listoflists:

```
listoflists = []
for i in range(1, number_of_needed_lists):
    listoflists.append((range(i), 0))
```

Comment: Isn't list.apend() the same as list += [] ?